# Microsoft Word 2007 restarts the installer upon exiting on Windows XP

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007

A user complained that they were having issues with MS Office 2007, and that the installation / configuration dialog kept appearing.  I already tried uninstalling Office 2007 and I ended up needing to use the Microsoft Fix It package to uninstall it, since using the control panel failed.

1. I close Microsoft Word.
2. The Installer for Microsoft Office inexplicably opens. 
    [image]
3. I then get a dialog that says I need to reboot. 
    [image]
4. So I restart...
5. Start Microsoft Word, Word starts up, and everything appears to be fine.
6. I close word, and nothing much happens this is on the administrator account.
7. I think everything is fixed so I call the user over to come try their account out.
8. We login as the user, and the user tries to open a document in Word.
9. The Configuration Progress Window reappears.
10. It runs...and then Word appears.
11. I close it and it appears to work, no window.
12. I open it again and the Configuration Progress window appears yet again...
13. Then Word opens up again, if I exit out and open up again I get the same Configuration Progress window.

I have no idea what is causing the Configuration Progress Window to come up..

**Update:** I attempted to install two updates:
Update for Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 Junk Email Filter (KB2687400)
Update for the 2007 Microsoft Office System (KB967642)

Both of these updates failed.

**Update:** I attempted to install [KB967642](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=21751) manually and it failed.

Comment: I'm starting to think maybe the updates downloaded badly, I'm going to try and delete them.

Comment: Does this happen with all the Office programs? Is there another version of office or run time installed?

Comment: Check out [Every time I open Microsoft Office Word 2007, it goes through a "Configuration Process"](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/every-time-i-open-microsoft-office-word-2007-it/4abcbf70-944a-40df-a092-8f17cb9accfd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are the installer is trying to set permissions on a registry key that it doesn't have permissions on and is therefore leaving the installation half complete. If you're lucky the event viewer might tell you which key this is related to and you could manually give non-administrators access to that key.

The real answer is probably a machine rebuild as I don't think cleaning out MS Office will do it - too many registry keys involved.

Comment: I agree, start over. Or take this as an excuse to get rid of the 8 year old OS and upgrade.

Comment: Yeah my boss just told me to swap out the machine with another one so you're probably right.  Man I despise the registry.